# How to access object on Vue front end from axios proxy

Tags: vue.js, object, mongoose, axios, get

I have a locally hosted mongodb database with mongoose, express, axios, and a Vue front end. Right now I'm trying to access a single object from an exported array, but I'm missing the mark and getting "undefined" as the result.

vue.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    proxy: 'http://localhost:3000',
  }
}
```

here's the front end Vue script meant to use the objects:

```
import axios from 'axios';

export default {
  name: 'Game',
  data () {
    return {
      pages: [],
      currentPage: {},

      pageTitle: "",
      pageText: "",
      options: [],
    }
  },
  created () {
    this.getPages();
  },
  methods: {
    async getPages() {
      try {
        let res = await axios.get('/api/pages');
        this.pages = res.data;
        console.log(this.pages);

        this.currentPage = this.pages[0];
        console.log(this.currentPage);

        return true;
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    },
```

my "get" endpoint in pages.js:

```
router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    let pages = await Page.find();
    res.send({pages: pages}); //send result of search for pages as list of pages called "pages"
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    res.sendStatus(500); //500 = server could not fulfill request
  }
});
```

the route in server.js:

```
const pages = require('./routes/pages');
app.use('/api/pages', pages);

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Server listening on port 3000!'));

module.exports = app;
```

and here's the console output, with the "pages" object from vue's data property and the "currentPage" that's supposed to be at pages[0] (printed to console in earlier example):
[image]

I can access the api at 'localhost:3000/api/pages' just fine, but how do I break into that array and access the first page object? I want to get an object from the list axios fetches from mongoose, then hold that object in a variable so I can access it's properties. The whole "pages > [[Target]] > pages > [ ]" is part of the problem I'm sure, but I don't know what to tell the code to open it.

Answer (score 0):

Whoops! I realized my mistake. In pages.js I should have sent "res.send(pages);" After a whole couple days too XD